# Will cloudflare workers being used as an API be able to handle 10,000 Requests per second?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have to create an API which handles occasionally high number of requests like bursts of 10,000 requests for few seconds. I will just add the request payload to KV and return success.

I have two questions

1. Will I have any significant cold starts(more than 500ms)
2. Will cloudflare workers be able to handle that occasional burst of requests.

Comment: from the documentation:  There is no general limit to the number of requests per second Workers can handle. Cloudflare’s abuse protection methods do not affect well-intentioned traffic. However, if you send many thousands of requests per second from a small number of client IP addresses, you can inadvertently trigger Cloudflare’s abuse protection. If you expect to receive 1015 errors in response to traffic or expect your application to incur these errors, contact your Cloudflare account team to increase your limit.

The burst rate and daily request limits apply at the account level

Comment: documentation detailing the limits can be found here:   https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/limits/#request

Comment: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/workers-requests-per-second/263338 - there is some discussion here that simply says its not that straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

1. No, you should not see cold starts over 500ms. Even if your app runs an expensive computation at startup, Workers actually applies a 200ms hard limit on such computation, which is detected at deploy time. So if your Worker successfully deploys, it should never take more than 500ms to start (unless Cloudflare is suffering from some sort of internal problem). Most apps take more like 10ms to "cold start", and this can usually be [parallelized with the TLS handshake](https://blog.cloudflare.com/eliminating-cold-starts-with-cloudflare-workers/) such that no cold start is observed at all.
2. As long as you are on a paid plan, Workers will have no problem scaling to 10,000 requests per second, even if it is sudden. Workers has customers that do orders of magnitude more traffic than that.

(I am the tech lead for Cloudflare Workers.)